# What does this Chrome icon mean?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, windows-8.1

Since today my Chrome browser has a pizza slice on its icon on the taskbar.

[image]

I just restarted my PC without exiting Chrome. So its been forced to quit by the Windows system. After the restart I had to press the button to recover my tabs. So now everything is the same as before, except that Chrome makes me hungry now.

**What is the meaning of the pizza slice in Chrome?**

I've read that this is connected to user profiles, but then I don't understand why it's appearing now as I'm using my profile for a long time.

*BTW I guess its a Pizza Special. Cheese, white mushrooms, salami and ham. I don't even like salami.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to **Settings** in Google Chrome
  If you don't know where they are, you can just paste this into the search bar:

**chrome://settings/**

- Look for the "**People**" section
- There you'll find the current users as well as buttons for **add**, **remove**, or **edit**

(You could **add** your own profile with your own icon.

Just **remove**/delete the other user(s) **and/or** uncheck the box that says "*let anyone add a person to Chrome*"

Or you could keep the user and just **edit** the information for it.)

Hope this helps :)

---

Try this then:

- chrome://flags/#enable-new-avatar-menu
- Select Disabled and restart browser.

Your Google+ picture shows because you've linked your Google+ account with your Chrome account. That's what I have showing right now. You can edit that though if you don't like it by going to:

Settings>People>Click on your user>Edit> And just choose the image you want.

Comment: Yes, this helped and I can change the icon depending on my profile. But still I wonder why it changes over time. Last time it was a pizza slice, then it changed over time to nothing. Now I restarted and I see my Google+ Profile picture. I do know now that it's related to my profile - but why does it change over time / by restart?

Comment: @Trollwut Chrome updates often, so it's possible the behavior changed slightly between versions of Chrome. I'm pretty sure the icon only shows if you have multiple profiles set up, and you can change the icon used in Chrome's settings page.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Google Help Forum discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?hl=en&tid=446610d53e5c09d8), Chrome’s developers are adding the ability to have multiple profiles in Chrome. The pizza icon would be one of several you could choose to indicate which profile is active. If you click on the icon now, you’ll see several other choices.

if the chrome is enabled with multiple users you could switch over from it,other than that its just representing your user profile icon at chrome

otherprofiles

Comment: Well but this discussion is from 2011. Why is it appearing NOW after 4 years? As I said, I just restarted and didn't change anything.

Comment: More suspicious: I let the browser run now for about 5 hours and it's gone.  Now I have a simple Chrome icon again. Google conspiracy?